# How can I calculate the iteration of multiple dates in two columns without eliminating entries?

Tags: ms-access

Currently I have two queries that i run to calculate the weekly input and output of product based off of the date it was received and the date that the job was closed.

I would like to combine these two queries into one so I can output a single chart with the combined data rather than having multiple charts.

Below is code from one of the queries.

```
SELECT [Product Log].ID,

[Product Log].[Date Closed],

[Product Log].[Inspected by]

FROM [Product Log]

WHERE (((Year([Date Closed])*53+DatePart("ww",[Date Closed]))=Year(Date())*53+DatePart("ww",Date())-1));
```

This Query pulls the data from the last week which allows me to calculate the daily output for that week.

The other is basically the same just pulling from a different column in the Product Log table and it omits the Inspected By field which i use for a different calculation.

What I am trying to do is something like this.

```
SELECT [Product Log].ID,

[Product Log].[Receipt Date],

[Product Log].[Date Closed],

[Product Log].[Inspected by],

IIf(IsNull([Date Closed]),0,1) AS Inspected,

IIf(IsNull([Receipt Date]),0,1) AS Received

FROM [Product Log];
```

Basically it just outputs a 1 or 0 that is counted so I can get my input/output calculation.

The issue I am having is that i cannot use the WHERE function because it will omit data from the Receipt Date column, and the reasoning for that is because something may have entered the facility several months ago but has not been inspected for whatever reason.

I tried using something like a between the last few days statement but it does not encompass what I need, nor could I get it to work properly, it just counts data regardless of that statement.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try building another query that joins the 2 queries. Edit question to post sample data, as text not image, if you need more help.

Comment: `[Product Log]` or `[Product Deviation Log]`?

Comment: Product Log, I have corrected the line.

Comment: @June7 I have attempted doing a union query but had the same results. I will attempt one again later and post back with a some of the table fields,code for the union query and the output.